# Can you edit an imported XPS model in Blender?

Tags: mesh

I have found some cool models in XPS ripped from some games and have imported them into Blender using an import plugin. But I went to make an adjustment to the character and found that I cannot edit. I cannot selection or see any vertices.

Other than rigging a skeleton is there a way to edit?

I believe I was in Modeling/Edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

How it work? I think that you do not need to explain how to install the addon, and simple operations in the blender!
Launch your blender! In object mode, search menu XPS Tools! (on the left side of your monitor screen)
Or just standart import:  File, Import, XNALara XPS model (ascii/mesh/xps)

Then after loading model, in outliner window (on the right, and up, on you monitor) you see armature of models, in scene!
Click Left-click on Eye icons, and close armature! After that, right-click on any model body, and push Tab! (Or enter edit mode) Enjoy! Your model editible)